# AKS cluster - create container image using CRI runtime

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

On Azure AKS I have deployed three node cluster, then I used `.yaml` file in order to deploy application. I have prepared Kubernetes object `DeamonSet`. It created three PODs, on each POD it deployed container with security application installed. On AKS node I have CRI container runtime instead of Docker runtime. My goal is to prepare app container image. My question is how to prepare container image using CRI runtime? I check Kubernetes documentation -->  [Docker - CRI commands mapping](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/tools/map-crictl-dockercli/), and there is no commands for image creation, in case of Docker we have `docker commit` command, we can use it for image preparation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRI is the [Container Runtime Interface](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cri/). The purpose is the have a standard protocol for the communication between the kubelet and Container Runtime.

The [container runtime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) can be docker, CRI-O or containerd. For [AKS the default runtime since 1.19 is containerd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/aks/cluster-configuration). All these runtimes can run [OCI images](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec) or also falsely (and widely) known as docker image or container image.

So if you create an OCI conform container image with docker your can run it on all container runtimes and also with kubernetes.

Comment: ok, understand it, on AKS by default we are using containerd, but how to prepare an image, I am looking for command similar to Docker "docker commit", I just need to prepare container based on container deployed on the POD. Currently I can use crictl commands on my AKS node.

Comment: Lets assume that I am connected to one of the NODEs and want to create an image of container running inside this POD where I am logged in. How can I do in using crictl commands.

Comment: why you want to do that? its a clear anti-pattern...you should always build your image withing the CI and not modify it during runtime.....but just to help you:  nerdctl is a docker like cli build for containerd = https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl